# tomcat server fails to start the server and application in STS

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc, tomcat7, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I run a Spring MVC application I get this exception and the sever fails to start.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Exception StackTrace:

```
Jan 24, 2013 11:33:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [org/springframework/instrument/classloading/oc4j/package-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/D:/works/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/dailyship/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:677)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:413)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2104)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1980)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1931)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1325)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The jar file may be corrupt as a result of bad internet connection. Try removing the content of your `C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository` folder. Then right click your project, select **Maven**, **Update Project**, check on **Force Update of Snapshots/Releases**.  If you are sure only one Jar file has a problem, then you only need to delete its folder.

Comment: Why can't the exception name which dependency has a problem? Why we have to clean the entire repo for one corrupt jar?

Comment: I have no idea what was causing the problems (what file exactly), but removing the maven folder and re-downloading dependencies / rebuilding them - helped...

Answer (score 3):

As newbie has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts#14495552) to clean up local maven repository, you can do it by executing `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`, which will delete the jars from local-repo and re-download them.

Answer (score 3):

- close your IDE
- delete the `.jar` file located in
  `(workspace_folder_location)/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/dailyship/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`
- open your IDE

If you work with maven:

- Right click on the project
- Maven `->` Update Project `->` check Force Update of snapshot/Releases

Comment: I think you should , rename the place where  `.metadata ` folder is located 
not  `D:/works ` ?

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS. Navigate to `~/.m2/` and run
`rm -rf repository/`

Then reimport all your maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem because of dependencies which are available in pom.xml file,some of them are corrupted.I resolve that by simply removing .m2/repository folder contents and followed this steps.

1. Run as ->  Maven clean.
2. Run as ->  Maven Install.(Use good internet provider)
3. maven -> Update project.

It will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Delete all the files on your local repo directory that causes error. Do maven clean, maven install and re-deploy your files in server. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above do not helped me. But after **restarting PC** on which Spring MVC application was running and issue has disappeared. It can be helpful for those who will face with the same problem.