# ReflectionToStringBuilder errors in Maven Project

Tags: spring, jsf, maven

Some of my Roo generated .aj files seem to be generating errors as below. I can see commons-lang3-3.1.jar in my Maven Dependencies.  I have added this to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>            
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>          
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) on
>   project AdminDirect-Model: Compiler errors : [ERROR] error at return
>   ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this,
>   ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);

I have a multi-module project, and when in STS I try to do a right click and Update Project, I get another annoying error saying "Problems Encountered while setting project description"...although this is probably a separate issue.

As an aside if anyone knows of the correct workflow to create a multi-module spring roo, JSF, JPA application (Model and Web tier under a parent module) that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: lang3 uses packages: `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder` old lang used `org.apache.commons.lang.builder`. Check if you not mixed both

Comment: Hi,  this is roo generated?  roo created in my Roo_To_String.aj 

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

Comment: in fact when I try to open the class file from the Maven Dependencies jar i get "Could not open the editor: invalid LOC header (bad signature)"

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the .m2/repository folder contents and forced a fresh download using Maven Update Project and then forced a refresh of snapshots.  Seems to work, jars must have been corrupt?

[tomcat server fails to start the server and application in STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts)

Comment: If this solved your problem, you may well accept your own answer!