# JSTL library error

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jstl

I've been receiving some errors that hinders my app from working. What did I do wrong?

```
    SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport.class] from Jar [jar:file:/K:/iACADEMY/3rd%20Year%201st%20Sem/Ent%20Java%202/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/lib/jstl-1.2.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Oct 03, 2016 4:12:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config.class] from Jar [jar:file:/K:/iACADEMY/3rd%20Year%201st%20Sem/Ent%20Java%202/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/lib/jstl-1.2.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Oct 03, 2016 4:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport.class] from Jar [jar:file:/K:/iACADEMY/3rd%20Year%201st%20Sem/Ent%20Java%202/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/lib/jstl-1.2.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Oct 03, 2016 4:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config.class] from Jar [jar:file:/K:/iACADEMY/3rd%20Year%201st%20Sem/Ent%20Java%202/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/lib/jstl-1.2.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm suppose to use a JSTL foreach function but somehow this error occurs after processing. This is the error trace that is shown on my console.

Comment: It looks like the file is corrupted. I would use another version of the jar you are trying to use.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the path of the jar file.

```
jar:file:/K:/iACADEMY/3rd%20Year%201st%20Sem/Ent%20Java%202/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/lib/jstl-1.2.jar!
```

I think you could rename the path with non space character and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It could be corrupted JAR as well, so for anyone who experience this error can chekck this as well: [tomcat server fails to start the server and application in STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts)