# Spring mvc project getting error invalid LOC header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I am developing spring mvc project on Liberty profile server. While starting liberty server getting following error.

I cleaned and install maven. I remove Liberty and configure again and added project into the server. Still getting same error.

Thanks.

```
    [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application demo. The exception message was: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Comment: I am using spring + liberty without any problems. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts

Comment: Yes it is helpful. resolved error by deleting C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem got resolved by following steps,

The jar file may be corrupted. I removed the content of C:\Users[username].m2\repository folder than follow below steps,

**Maven update**

Right click on project -> Select Maven -> click on "Update Project" wait for sometime to finish downloading and configuring

**Clean Maven**

Right click on project -> Select **Run as** -> click on **Clean Maven**

**Install Maven**

Right click on project -> Select **Run as** -> click on **Install Maven**

**invalid LOC header** error got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have added some libraries which are corrupt so 
delete the jars from local repository ie

> **c:/users/your pc name/m2/repository/search for your file and then delete**

now do maven build again on your child project *clean install* and then maven build on your parent project