# tomcat can not run success

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

and I am try change different tomcat version but it is not use

environment:
 1. eclipse 
 2. jdk1.8.0.111
 3. tomcat8.0.39

[errorMessage](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzaeqlTAK0ZfREJaajY4X1VSZmM)

Comment: Looks like one of the jar's/war's is corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar question which has been asked. There are some answers which solved the problem. [tomcat server fails to start the server and application in STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts)

Comment: Then you should suggest it as a duplicate. What you have posted is not an answer - it's either a comment that leads to an answer or it's a suggestion for a duplicate.