# Tomcat server (on localhost) failed to run after adding spring-security-config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I have a Spring-MVC project in Eclipse (Neon), in which I use Spring security. This has been set up with Maven. 
The details are:
 - Eclipse Neon
 - tomcat 8.5.9 (the same issue was also with tomcat 8.0), 
 - Spring 4.3.5
 - Spring security 4.2.1

When I add the spring-security-config dependency in the POM.xml file, tomcat fails to start, and I get the following:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/offers]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/offers]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@50d16c34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4974)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@1f030c21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
    ... 13 more

Ιαν 18, 2017 2:10:10 ΜΜ org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Ιαν 18, 2017 2:10:10 ΜΜ org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Ιαν 18, 2017 2:10:10 ΜΜ org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Ιαν 18, 2017 2:10:10 ΜΜ org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Ιαν 18, 2017 2:10:10 ΜΜ org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Ιαν 18, 2017 2:10:10 ΜΜ org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Ιαν 18, 2017 2:10:10 ΜΜ org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Ιαν 18, 2017 2:10:10 ΜΜ org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/offers]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
    at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5425)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1036)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1036)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:659)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

The POM.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.caveofprogramming.spring.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>offers</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.40</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

It's worth nothing that I have the same setup on another computer (but with Spring version 4.3.4 and Spring security 4.2.1) and it works without any problems.

I've set up the Eclipse project from scratch many times, but when I reach the point where I add the spring-security-config dependency, the tomcat fails to start when I run the project.
If I don't add the spring-security-config dependency, I get a "Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace" exception.
Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>COP_spring-mvc</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <description>MySQL Test App</description>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>Spring DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/spring</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/caveofprogramming/spring/web/config/dao-context.xml
        classpath:com/caveofprogramming/spring/web/config/security-context.xml
        classpath:com/caveofprogramming/spring/web/config/service-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: could you share your web.xml?

Comment: The relevant error message is `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)`. Always look at the innermost exception of the first stack trace. This seems to indicate that one of the jar files is corrupt.

Comment: General recommendation for this type of error seems to be to delete the Maven repository and redownload it: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/maven-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts.

Comment: Thank you for your response - it was indeed very helpful. I removed the MAVEN repository and rebuilt it, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: in search.maven.org search spring-security-web]- I had the same problem like yours.
- in search.maven.org search spring-security-web
Spring Security has two dependencies. (1) spring-security-web (2) spring-security-config.
And there is Spring security and other project Spring Framework (which covers core, aop, mvc). These are two separate projects. They operate on different release cycles. Version numbers between projects are generally not in sync (sigh ... very frustrating)( Spring team is working to resolve this for future releases).
- Common pitfall is using incompatible projects.
- I rerun the project using different versions of these two projects.
- Apparently this is your solution to your problem.
- So you need to find compatible versions between spring security and spring framework.
- Here is the list of compatible versions I found

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.1.5
Spring Security 5.1.5 was released on 2 April 2019. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.1.5 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.1.6
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below
5.1.6.RELEASE

### 5.1.5.RELEASE

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.1.4
Spring Security 5.1.4 was released on 14 February 2019. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.1.4 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.1.5
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below
5.1.5.RELEASE

### 5.1.4.RELEASE

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.1.3
Spring Security 5.1.3 was released on 10 January 2019. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.1.3 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.1.4
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.1.2
Spring Security 5.1.2 was released on 29 November 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.1.2 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.1.3
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.1.2.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.1.1
Spring Security 5.1.1 was released on 16 October 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.1.1 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.1.1
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.1.0
Spring Security 5.1.0 was released on 27 September 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.1.0 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.1.0
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.0.7
Spring Security 5.0.7 was released on 26 July 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.0.7 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.0.8
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.0.6
Spring Security 5.0.6 was released on 13 June 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.0.6 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.0.7
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.0.5
Spring Security 5.0.5 was released on 8 May 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.0.5 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.0.6
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.0.4
Spring Security 5.0.4 was released on 5 April 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.0.4 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.0.5
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.0.3
Spring Security 5.0.3 was released the week of 28 Feb 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.0.3 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.0.4
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.0.2
Spring Security 5.0.2 was released the week of 20 Feb 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.0.2 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.0.4
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

---

UPDATES Spring Security 5.0.1
Spring Security 5.0.1 was released the week of 24 Jan 2018. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.
Spring Security 5.0.1 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.0.3
If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>

<springsecurity.version>5.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```