# Unable to deploy my project in Tomcat 8.0:Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Everything worked properly until I deleted this project from Workspaces for loading and editing another project, when I reloaded the former project, it failed to start on Tomcat. I did not change anything of web.xml and other files, I tried several existing solutions on web like below but all failed:

1. make sure the Java Version of MyEclipse and Tomcat are the same.
2. try to delete the Tomcat, and redeploy the project.
3. check the web.xml (I changed nothing but it works properly before).
4. delete the whole Workspaces directory and restart the project.

here is a part of log in console:

```
信息: Deploying web application directory /Users/haohui/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps/ROOT
二月 18, 2017 1:02:38 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory /Users/haohui/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps/ROOT has finished in 14 ms
二月 18, 2017 1:02:38 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory /Users/haohui/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps/v3
二月 18, 2017 1:02:38 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
严重: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/v3]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@182cfd14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2dccbd5e]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
    ... 17 more
二月 18, 2017 1:02:38 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
严重: Error deploying web application directory /Users/haohui/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps/v3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/v3]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
二月 18, 2017 1:02:38 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory /Users/haohui/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps/v3 has finished in 28 ms
二月 18, 2017 1:02:38 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
信息: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
二月 18, 2017 1:02:38 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
信息: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
二月 18, 2017 1:02:38 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
信息: Server startup in 711 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be about Eclipse/Tomcat, it should be a jar dependency corrupted in your project. See : [tomcat server fails to start the server and application in STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts)

Maybe you didn't search for the good keywords : "invalid LOC header (bad signature)"