# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

```
Mar 14, 2017 12:46:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [org/springframework/security/authentication/AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/dev/saml/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/springsecuritysaml/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:679)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:415)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:236)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2055)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1931)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1897)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1314)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 14, 2017 12:46:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderNotFoundException.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/dev/saml/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/springsecuritysaml/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:679)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:415)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:236)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2055)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1931)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1897)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1314)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Inspite of clearing m2/repo folder and updating maven project, iam getting theses errors for all the jar files and for all the maven projects in my workspace .I have also set project facets and java build path, can anybody tell where the problem is?

Comment: Probably a corrupted JAR, try to remove it from your Maven repositories and re-download it.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jar file seems to be corrupted. Try removing the content from the `.m2\repository` and run `mvn clean install`

OR

Then right click your project, select `Maven -> Update Project -> check on Force Update of Snapshots/Releases.`