# How to resolve spring-boot-devtools dependency issue?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I added spring-boot-devtools dependency in pom.xml. When I run my application I got following exceptions. I am using spring-boot-parent-1.53.RELEASE version. How to resolve this issue?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read 
Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar 
file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-
classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromUrlClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:96)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:546)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
at com.company.Application.main(Application.java:11)

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromManifestClassPathAttribute(ChangeableUrls.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:107)
... 16 more`
```

Comment: try to look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts

Comment: Hello @NicomedesE. - Do I need to make my local repository empty?

Comment: If you are sure only one Jar file has a problem then you only need to delete its folder, otherwise delete all... I suggest to delete first logback-
classic...

Comment: Thanks @NicomedesE. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Even I got this error but with different jar.

I went to the local repository and deleted the jar file then it worked.

In your case

```
file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
```

try deleting this jar file and run your app before that have a backup of this jar.

Hope this helpful.

Comment: This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question. Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for your time.