# spring boot appication termination in ecllipse error

Tags: spring-boot

[image]
While running my application in spring boot I'm getting this error how can I solve it?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/bcss/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts try this, it is just the same problem

Comment: sir, I tried this. I cleared reposotory. But now it is taking too much time to download all the repositories again and building workspace.

Comment: it takes so much time only the first time

Comment: I done as insrtucted above, but now it indicates error parsing lifecycle processing instructions in pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

This will be shown when the file or jar is a corrupted one. It happens when the jar is not being downloaded fully. please remove the jar file to redownload. It may download the jar or full folder based on which is you deleted from that repository. for example, if you delete the jar only then that file will be downloaded. if you delete the folder the whole folder will be downloaded. I will prefer to delete the folder and let it download it as a new one

Comment: I done as insrtucted above, but now it indicates error parsing lifecycle processing instructions in pom.xml file. I need to download all files again? @arun johnson

Comment: did you use maven update? if not please update the project. While updating please tick force update.

Comment: . Did you deleted entire .m2???. Then you need to redownload all the dependencies. if you use maven update that will download all the dependencies. make sure you have a strong bandwidth

Comment: yes,I deleted entire .m2 and used maven update to redownload all the dependencies. now it indicates error in pom.xml, "error parsing life cycle processing system"@arun johnson

Comment: if you delete the whole .m2 then the program should work. Because it is downloading the new versions of the dependencies. Can you provide your pom.xml to reproduce the error??